# external link not working as field display value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm looking to have the display value working as an external link.

```
<a href="<%= contact.website %>"><%= contact.website %></a>
```

This is the current code, but its result does not bring focus out of the app.

I attempted a link_to.  This works but does not display the actual field value but the word "website" as the display.

```
<%= link_to("website", contact.website) %>
```

How can <%= contact.website %> have current syntax within the "" quotes?

Comment: What do you mean by "but its result does not bring focus out of the app". Do you need the link to open in another window/tab?

Comment: Yes, looking for opening up in another tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
<%= link_to(contact.website, contact.website, target: '_blank') %>
```

As you see, you can just provide `contact.website` as link text. Also, `target: '_blank'` will open the web in a new browser tab.

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered, @dgilperez  Hard to find in the rails docs. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:
`<%= link_to "#{contact.website}",contact.website %>`

Comment: no need for the unnecessary quotes and interpolation btw, other than that it's correct.